# PAM nologin not working?

Tags: login, users, user-management, pam, lock

Trying to learn basics of PAM and one thing I tried was to utilize the nologin feature.

So I simply made a file `/etc/nologin` with the text "Sorry, users locked out for now!"

I rebooted but for some reason everyone could still log in. And what's even weirder is that the file was gone.

What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: Is /etc/nologin readable by everyone? From the man page:  "If  the file /etc/nologin exists and is readable, login(1) will allow access only to root.
       Other users will be shown the contents of this file and their logins will be refused."

Comment: @jpezz permissions are rw-r--r-- so yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/etc/nologin` file is normally deleted on reboot, so nothing you are really doing wrong.
To test, just create the `/etc/nologin` and try to login via SSH or similar to see the message.

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong. If /etc/nologin remained after reboot, how would YOU login? That's why it is removed on reboot. /etc/pam.d/login is the controlling section. Changing pam.d files to allow your username to bypass the nologin check and not others so you are locked out as well as making the /etc/nologin file persistent is too hard for me to explain and problematical if one makes a mistake. There are numerous tutorials on pam if you do a web search on "pam.d".